# In Latent Dirichlet allocation, is the following formula the probability of observing a single document, or an entire corpus?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, dirichlet-distribution, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

This is the formula in question:
[image]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the entire corpus because, as per the explanation, $M$ is the number of documents in the collection, and the product goes over all documents, denoted by $j$.

Comment: Thank you, that was my conclusion as well from reading the article. I saw a YouTube video claiming that formula is for a single document and wanted to double-check with you guys.